# IComparer for natural sorting

Tags: c#, list, sorting, natural-sort

I have been hunting around for a solution to this for a while now.

When I sort the below using a string sort I have a list of:

```
10
10b
1111
1164
1174
23
23A
23B
23D
23E
```

I really want the list to be:

```
10
10b
23
23A
23B
23D
23E
1111
1164
1174
```

A numerical sort does not do the job either.

Comment: Why doesn't a numerical sort do the job?

Comment: take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/NaturalSortComparer.aspx

Comment: @pratapchandra - should just make your comment an official answer.

Comment: @Jagd i have done that i hope this will helps op .......

Answer (score 4):

If you have LINQ, you can use `OrderBy`:

```
Regex digitPart = new Regex(@"^\d+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
...
myList.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(digitPart.Match(x).Value))
```

Comment: Worked for me, but I had to change Integer.Parse to Int32.Parse, and .value should be capitalized. Syntax, meh...

Comment: @Jagd: Oops :P I'm a VB.NET person and it's `Integer` there.

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether the OP wants a full natural search that would also order "A1", "A2", "Bumblebee" in that order.

Comment: @minitech - Oh, duh. I should have realized that! *smacks head* :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest is to wrap the Win32 API call as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/248613/631687

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class NumStrCmp : IComparer<string> {
    public int Compare(string x, string y){
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<NumPart>\d+)(?<StrPart>\D*)",RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var mx = regex.Match(x);
        var my = regex.Match(y);
        var ret = int.Parse(mx.Groups["NumPart"].Value).CompareTo(int.Parse(my.Groups["NumPart"].Value));
        if(ret != 0) return ret;
        return mx.Groups["StrPart"].Value.CompareTo(my.Groups["StrPart"].Value);
    }
}

class Sample {
    static public void Main(){
        var data = new List<string>() {"10","10b","1111","1164","1174","23","23A","23B","23D","23E"};
        data.Sort(new NumStrCmp());
        foreach(var x in data){
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
   }
}
```