# Correct way for sorting a String array

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<String> lines = File.ReadLines("K:\\file.txt");
```

The file contains the following data

```
1
2
3
99
32
HR210
Redmond City Room A
23
Telephone Conference
HR252
```

Each line has 1 entry which represents a room in a building.

How do I sort it numerically and alphabetically. So my results look like

```
1
2
3
23
32
99
HR210
HR252
Redmond City Room A
Telephone Conference
```

The alphabetical part comes after the numbers.

Comment: You tried OrderBy() and it didn't satisfy you?

Comment: Another question would be:
Is 10 before or after 2?

Comment: Will you have any strings that _start_ with a number but contain alpha characters afterwards?  (e.g. `123ABC`).  If so how should those be sorted?

Comment: take a look at natural comparer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568696/icomparer-for-natural-sorting

Comment: why the downvote? Seems like a legitimate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `int.TryParse` and an anonymous type + `Enumerable.OrderBy`:

```
int i;
lines = lines
    .Select(l => new { Line = l, IsText = !int.TryParse(l, out i), Value = i })
    .OrderBy(x => x.IsText)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Value).ThenBy(x => x.Line)
    .Select(x => x.Line);
```

`.OrderBy(x => x.IsText)` returns a `bool` where `true` is "higher" than `false`. That's why all text-lines come last.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to implement your own IComparer.  You can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp) to easily create it, using built in functions.  If you must write it yourself, Tim's answer will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **Natural Comparing**.

[IComparer for natural sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568696/icomparer-for-natural-sorting)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22517/Natural-Sort-Comparer