# vb.net sorted list sorting order not in the correct order

Tags: vb.net, sortedlist

I'm trying to use a sorted list, but it seems not to sort the way I want it to sort. I have a list with **string** values.

```
2
4
7
1
3
5
6
8
9
10
```

When added these values into my sorted list it's returned as:

```
1
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I know that it's because I sort string numbers that this happens but how can you avoid this?

Why are these values entered as string? There is a possibility for sub-numbers
like 1.1; 1.2; 1.3.. So the string type must be retained, I can't convert to doubles because 1,1 & 1,10 would give me a error being the same value.

How can you sort these values that 10 come after 9 instead of after 1?

Add: code to add items to the list

```
oBOMList.Add(oItemNumber, oIndex)
```

Comment: please show us the code you're using to populate and sort the list. That might help us to spot any mistakes with casting, sorting, etc. Thanks :)

Comment: You are after the algorithm named [Natural Sort](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on the internet, thanks to the comments I was able to create better search as before. Thanks all!

Public Class AlphanumComparator
    Implements IComparer

```
Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object,
            ByVal y As Object) As Integer Implements IComparer.Compare

    ' [1] Validate the arguments.
    Dim s1 As String = x
    If s1 = Nothing Then
        Return 0
    End If

    Dim s2 As String = y
    If s2 = Nothing Then
        Return 0
    End If

    Dim len1 As Integer = s1.Length
    Dim len2 As Integer = s2.Length
    Dim marker1 As Integer = 0
    Dim marker2 As Integer = 0

    ' [2] Loop over both Strings.
    While marker1 < len1 And marker2 < len2

        ' [3] Get Chars.
        Dim ch1 As Char = s1(marker1)
        Dim ch2 As Char = s2(marker2)

        Dim space1(len1) As Char
        Dim loc1 As Integer = 0
        Dim space2(len2) As Char
        Dim loc2 As Integer = 0

        ' [4] Collect digits for String one.
        Do
            space1(loc1) = ch1
            loc1 += 1
            marker1 += 1

            If marker1 < len1 Then
                ch1 = s1(marker1)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop While Char.IsDigit(ch1) = Char.IsDigit(space1(0))

        ' [5] Collect digits for String two.
        Do
            space2(loc2) = ch2
            loc2 += 1
            marker2 += 1

            If marker2 < len2 Then
                ch2 = s2(marker2)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop While Char.IsDigit(ch2) = Char.IsDigit(space2(0))

        ' [6] Convert to Strings.
        Dim str1 = New String(space1)
        Dim str2 = New String(space2)

        ' [7] Parse Strings into Integers.
        Dim result As Integer
        If Char.IsDigit(space1(0)) And Char.IsDigit(space2(0)) Then
            Dim thisNumericChunk = Integer.Parse(str1)
            Dim thatNumericChunk = Integer.Parse(str2)
            result = thisNumericChunk.CompareTo(thatNumericChunk)
        Else
            result = str1.CompareTo(str2)
        End If

        ' [8] Return result if not equal.
        If Not result = 0 Then
            Return result
        End If
    End While

    ' [9] Compare lengths.
    Return len1 - len2
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a custom implementation of `IComparer(Of T)` to handle sorting strings the way you want.  You can then tell your sorted list to use this comparer to sort the items in the list.  The comparer will basically teach your list how to determine whether one items is higher or lower than another item in the list.  You could use this to create any kind of crazy sorting behavior you need.

- You can find documentation and an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf(v=vs.110).aspx).
- There is an
  implementation of Natural Sort as an `IComparer` in one of the answers
  to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568696/icomparer-for-natural-sorting) question.

Comment: I'm not great in these things, but i checked the demo on the code and that works great. Now I only need to get it in .net and not C#. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I use the following extension method to do an alphanumeric sort on a list (quickly converted from C#):

```
''' <summary>
''' Used to order the given array alphanumerically
''' </summary>
''' <typeparam name="T">the type</typeparam>
''' <param name="source">the source object</param>
''' <param name="selector">the item being used as the selector</param>
''' <returns>the sorted list</returns>
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function OrderByAlphanumeric(Of T)(source As IEnumerable(Of T), selector As Func(Of T, [String])) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Try
        Dim max As Int32
        Try
            max = source.SelectMany(Of Int32)(Function(i) Regex.Matches(selector(i), "\d+").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Of Int32)(Function(m) m.Value.Length)).Max()
        Catch ex As Exception
            max = 0
        End Try

        Return source.OrderBy(Function(i) Regex.Replace(selector(i), "\d+", Function(m) m.Value.PadLeft(max, "0"c)))
    Catch exMain As Exception
        Return source
    End Try
End Function
```